# SaveToDatabase in TYPO3 8

Tags: database, forms, typo3

How to use form finisher SaveToDataBase in TYPO3 8.7.1? I try to add finisher in YAML, but I have an error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\SaveToDatabaseFinisher::process() must
>   be of the type integer, string given, called in
>   typo3\sysext\form\Classes\Domain\Finishers\SaveToDatabaseFinisher.php
>   on line 207

YAML document:

```
renderingOptions:
  submitButtonLabel: Submit
type: Form
identifier: form
label: Form
prototypeName: standard
finishers:
  -
    options:
      table: table1
      mode: update
      whereClause:
        uid: '1'
      elements:
        text-1:
          mapOnDatabaseColumn: column1
    identifier: SaveToDatabase
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'previous Page'
      nextButtonLabel: 'next Page'
    type: Page
    identifier: page-1
    label: Page
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: text-1
        label: Text
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a YAML form. What you present is a YAML document and it is valid. Any interpretation as a form would be done by typo3 internals.

Comment: @Anthon this is not correct. TYPO3 v8 comes with a completely rewritten form framework. Both, the configuration and form definition is based on YAML. Check out the docs for more information: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/drafts/code.tritum.de/TYPO3.CMS/Form_Documentation/Index.html

Comment: @Sergey Please read https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/drafts/code.tritum.de/TYPO3.CMS/Form_Documentation/ApiReference/Index.html#savetodatabase-finisher.

Comment: @Björn Please refer to the YAML specification (preferable the latest) when trying to prove me incorrect, there is no mention of forms in there. I never indicated that Typo 3 has no forms, but what it has are not YAML forms. Those are *Typo 3 forms* specified using the YAML format, conceptually something entirely different (and possible). In the same way Typo 3 has no ASCII or UTF-8 forms (assuming Typo 3 uses ASCII or UTF-8 ..). Such distinction might seem subtle, but they are important.

Comment: Nobody ever said there is a YAML form. But you are right, TYPO3 uses YAML to configure the form framework and define forms.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same TYPO3 exception. Try to write the options as an array, using `-`. This solved the problem for me.

```
renderingOptions:
  submitButtonLabel: Submit
type: Form
identifier: form
label: Form
prototypeName: standard
finishers:
  -
    options:
      -
        table: 'table1'
        mode: update
        whereClause:
          uid: '1'
        elements:
          text-1:
            mapOnDatabaseColumn: column1
    identifier: SaveToDatabase
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'previous Page'
      nextButtonLabel: 'next Page'
    type: Page
    identifier: page-1
    label: Page
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: text-1
        label: Text
```

Comment: Can you write here how exactly to write?

Comment: I already updated your code example in my answer. Below the line `options:` I added a new line containing a dash `-`. This describes an array (or _sequence_, as it is called in YAML). The code below has to be indented by two spaces.

Comment: This, is excellent! It is NOT in the docs, so I assume, this is a bug in EXT:form, or at least an unwanted behaviour ...
For me, your solution works definitively!

Answer (score 0):

Example from typo3\sysext\form\Classes\Domain\Finishers\SaveToDatabaseFinisher.php

```
 * =======
 *
 *  finishers:
 *    -
 *      identifier: SaveToDatabase
 *      options:
 *        table: 'fe_users'
 *        mode: update
 *        whereClause:
 *          uid: 1
 *        databaseColumnMappings:
 *          pid:
 *            value: 1
 *        elements:
 *          text-1:
 *            mapOnDatabaseColumn: 'first_name'
 *          text-2:
 *            mapOnDatabaseColumn: 'last_name'
 *          text-3:
 *            mapOnDatabaseColumn: 'username'
 *          advancedpassword-1:
 *            mapOnDatabaseColumn: 'password'
 *            skipIfValueIsEmpty: true
 *
```

Maybe I missed something?